# Nested GroupBy & Aggregation in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

I am trying to `groupBy` based on the `ResourceId` & `Category` and return the corresponding highest severity level available.
The severity hierarchy is Critical > Major > Minor. i.e After grouping by `ResourceId` & `Category`, we need to return the highest severity for the group.

```
case class Issue(
  resourceId: String, 
  Category: String, 
  Severity: String, 
  incidentType: String
)

case class IssueStatus(
  resourceId:String, 
  Hardware: Option[String],
  Network: Option[String], 
  Software: Option[String]
)

List(
  Issue("r1", "Network", "Critical", "incident1"),
  Issue("r1", "Network", "Major", "incident2"),
  Issue("r1", "Hardware", "Minor", "incident 3"),
  Issue("r2", "Hardware", "Major", "incident 3"),
  Issue("r3", "Software", "Minor", "incident 1"),
)
```

**Expected Output**:

```
List(
  IssueStatus("r1", Some("Minor"), Some("Critical"), None),
  IssueStatus("r2", Some("Major"), None, None),
  IssueStatus("r3", None, None, Some("Minor"))
)
```

Update:

The Category is mapped to the case object. i.e We only have 3 categories: Network, Hardware & Software.

For each resource, I want to know what is the Highest severity within each category. If the Network category has highest severity as Critical and the there are no entries for the categories of Software & Hardware, for resource `r5`, then the corresponding `IssueStatus` would be like

```
IssueStatus("r5", None, Some("Critical"), None)
```

Comment: Can you make the severity an enum?

Comment: I also don't understand the transformation between an issue and the issue status...

Comment: @erip

The Category is mapped to the case object. i.e We only have 3 categories: Network, Hardware & Software.

For each resource, I want to know what is the Highest severity within each category. If the Network category has highest severity as Critical and the there are no entries for the categories of Software & Hardware, for resource r5, then the corresponding IssueStatus would be like
`IssueStatus("r1", None, Some("Critical"), None)`

Comment: you might want to read about enumerations or algebraic data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this does what you are looking for:

```
def highestIssueStatus(issues: List[Issue]): IssueStatus = {
  def issueRank(issue: Issue): Int =
    List("Minor", "Major", "Critical").indexOf(issue.Severity)

  val high = issues
      .groupBy(_.Category)
      .mapValues(_.maxBy(issueRank).Severity)

    IssueStatus(
      issues.head.resourceId,
      high.get("Hardware"),
      high.get("Network"),
      high.get("Software")
    )
}

list.groupBy(_.resourceId).values.map(highestIssueStatus)
```

#### Update

Thanks to Yaneeve for point out the error in the original (`issueRank` was looking a `_.Category` rather than `_.Severity`)

#### Optimisation

Following the comment from the OP, here is a more optimised and less functional solution to this problem. It builds the answers into a mutable map in a single pass rather than using `groupBy` and then processing the results.

```
val categories = Vector("Hardware", "Network", "Software")
val severities = Vector("Minor", "Major", "Critical")
val results = Vector(None) ++ severities.map(Some(_))

def parseIssues(issues: List[Issue]) = {
  val issueMap = mutable.Map.empty[String, ArrayBuffer[Int]]

  issues.foreach{ issue =>
    val cat = categories.indexOf(issue.Category) + 1
    val sev = severities.indexOf(issue.Severity) + 1
    val cur = issueMap.get(issue.resourceId) match {
      case Some(v) => v
      case None =>
        val n = ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 0, 0)
        issueMap(issue.resourceId) = n
        n
    }

    if (cur(cat) < sev) {
      cur(cat) = sev
    }
  }

  issueMap.map{ case (k, v) =>
    IssueStatus(k, results(v(1)), results(v(2)), results(v(3)))
  }
}
```

Another optimisation would be to use scalar values rather than `String` for the categories and severities. This would avoid the need for the `indexOf` calls in the main loop and allow the `mutable.Map` to store `Option[Severity]` directly rather than as an index into `results`.

This approach could also be used in a streaming mode where status updates are continually added to the `Map` as they come in and the latest status could be extracted at any point. The map values are mutable so the status for a resource could be reset to `0`(`None`) when an issue is cleared. Thread-safety issues need to be considered here so this could, for example, be placed in an `Akka Actor`.

Comment: For some reason, your solution and mine don't produce the same results on my sample input. Mine is `List(IssueStatus(r3,None,Some(Major),Some(Minor)), IssueStatus(r2,Some(Critical),None,None), IssueStatus(r1,Some(Major),Some(Critical),None))
`, while yours is: `List(IssueStatus(r3,None,Some(Major),Some(Minor)), IssueStatus(r2,Some(Major),None,None), IssueStatus(r1,Some(Major),Some(Critical),None))`

Comment: Thanks @Tim. Works like a charm. I will be executing this function on 100K records. Do we have any performance tunings we can do?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on the "issue".

```
val input = List(
  Issue("r1", "Network", "Critical", "incident1"),
  Issue("r1", "Network", "Major", "incident2"),
  Issue("r1", "Hardware", "Minor", "incident 3"),
  Issue("r2", "Hardware", "Major", "incident 3"),
  Issue("r3", "Software", "Minor", "incident 1"),
  Issue("r3", "Software", "Critical", "incident 1"), // added 2 more for testing
  Issue("r3", "Software", "Major", "incident 1"),
)

val res = input.groupBy(_.resourceId)
  .mapValues(_.groupBy(_.Category)
    .mapValues(_.map(_.Severity).min))
  .map{ case (k,m) => 
    IssueStatus(k, m.get("Hardware"), m.get("Network"), m.get("Software"))
  }.toList

//res: List[IssueStatus] = List(IssueStatus(r3,None,None,Some(Critical))
//                            , IssueStatus(r2,Some(Major),None,None)
//                            , IssueStatus(r1,Some(Minor),Some(Critical),None))
```

Note: there's an unfortunate little hack in that it relies on the alphabetical order of "Critical", "Major", and "Minor", with the earlier taking precedence over the latter. This wouldn't work if `Severity` strings were "Bad", "Very Bad", and "Doomed".

Comment: '@jwvh.. could you please help me in getting the final step in my solution.

Comment: @jwvh Thanks, Looks short & Neat. I will be executing this function on 100K records. Do we have any performance tunings we can do?

Answer (score 1):

One more take on the solution :)

```
val input = List(
  Issue("r1", "Network", "Critical", "incident1"),
  Issue("r1", "Network", "Major", "incident2"),
  Issue("r1", "Hardware", "Major", "incident5"),
  Issue("r1", "Hardware", "Minor", "incident 3"),
  Issue("r2", "Hardware", "Major", "incident 6"),
  Issue("r2", "Hardware", "Critical", "incident 13"),
  Issue("r3", "Software", "Minor", "incident 1"),
  Issue("r3", "Network", "Major", "incident 1"),
)


val ranked = input.groupBy(_.resourceId).flatMap {case (resourceId, issuesByResource) =>
    issuesByResource.groupBy(_.Category). map { case (category, issuesByCategoryPerResource) =>
      implicit val _ : Ordering[Issue] = (lhs: Issue, rhs: Issue) => {
        (lhs.Severity, rhs.Severity) match {
          case ("Critical", _) => -1
          case (_, "Critical") => 1
          case ("Major", _) => -1
          case (_, "Major") => 1
          case _ => -1
        }
      }
      (resourceId, category, issuesByCategoryPerResource.min.Severity)
    }
}


val grouped = ranked.groupBy(_._1)
val resourceIdToRawIssueStatus = grouped.mapValues { _. map {case (_, cat, sev) => cat -> sev}.toMap}

resourceIdToRawIssueStatus.map{ case (rId, statusesByCat) =>
    IssueStatus(rId, statusesByCat.get("Hardware"), statusesByCat.get("Network"), statusesByCat.get("Software"))
}
```

Small note, I don't usually like to use [`mapValues`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/concurrent/Map.html#mapValues[W](f:V=%3EW):scala.collection.Map[K,W]) since it is actually a "view"

Answer (score 0):

```
case class Issue(
                 resourceId: String,
                 Category: String,
                 Severity: String,
                 incidentType: String
               )

case class IssueStatus(
                       resourceId: String,
                       Hardware: Option[String],
                       Network: Option[String],
                       Software: Option[String]
                      )

val p = List(
    Issue("r1", "Network", "Critical", "incident1"),
    Issue("r1", "Hardware", "Minor", "incident 3"),
    Issue("r2", "Hardware", "Major", "incident 3"),
    Issue("r3", "Software", "Minor", "incident 1")
  )

def getIssues(lstOfIssue: List[Issue], typeOfIssue: String): Option[String] = {
    lstOfIssue.find(_.Category == typeOfIssue) match {
      case Some(v) => Some(v.Severity)
      case _ => None
    }
  }

def computeIssueStatus(listOfIssues: List[Issue]): List[IssueStatus] = {
    listOfIssues.groupBy(issue => issue.resourceId)
      .map(kv =>
        IssueStatus(kv._1, getIssues(kv._2, "Hardware"), getIssues(kv._2, "Network"), getIssues(kv._2, "Software")))
      .toList
  }
computeIssueStatus(p)
```

Comment: You appear to have missed a key point, and adjusted your test suite accordingly. `Issue(r1,Network,Critical,...` is supposed to take precedent over `Issue(r1,Network,Major,...`, no matter what order they appear in the data list.

Answer (score -1):

I'm close to the final step. Still working on merging the IssueStatus based on resourceId. Check this.

```
scala> case class Issue(
     |   resourceId: String,
     |   Category: String,
     |   Severity: String,
     |   incidentType: String
     | )
defined class Issue

scala> case class IssueStatus(
     |   resourceId:String,
     |   Hardware: Option[String],
     |   Network: Option[String],
     |   Software: Option[String]
     | )
defined class IssueStatus

scala>

scala> val issueList = List(
     |   Issue("r1", "Network", "Critical", "incident1"),
     |   Issue("r1", "Network", "Major", "incident2"),
     |   Issue("r1", "Hardware", "Minor", "incident 3"),
     |   Issue("r2", "Hardware", "Major", "incident 3"),
     |   Issue("r3", "Software", "Minor", "incident 1")
     | )
issueList: List[Issue] = List(Issue(r1,Network,Critical,incident1), Issue(r1,Network,Major,incident2), Issue(r1,Hardware,Minor,incident 3), Issue(r2,Hardware,Major,incident 3), Issue(r3,Software,Minor,incident 1))

scala> val proc1 = issueList.groupBy( x=> (x.resourceId,x.Category)).map( x=>(x._1,(x._2).sortWith( (p,q) => p.Category > q.Category)(0))).map( x=> (x._1._1,x._1._2,x._2.Severity))
proc1: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[(String, String, String)] = List((r1,Hardware,Minor), (r3,Software,Minor), (r2,Hardware,Major), (r1,Network,Critical))

scala> val proc2 = proc1.map( x => x match { case(a,"Hardware",c) => IssueStatus(a,Some(c),None,None) case(a,"Network",c) => IssueStatus(a,None,Some(c),None) case(a,"Software",c) => IssueStatus(a,None,None,Some(c)) } )
proc2: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[IssueStatus] = List(IssueStatus(r1,Some(Minor),None,None), IssueStatus(r3,None,None,Some(Minor)), IssueStatus(r2,Some(Major),None,None), IssueStatus(r1,None,Some(Critical),None))

scala>

scala> proc2.foreach(println)
IssueStatus(r1,Some(Minor),None,None)
IssueStatus(r3,None,None,Some(Minor))
IssueStatus(r2,Some(Major),None,None)
IssueStatus(r1,None,Some(Critical),None)

scala>
```

Comment: You're sorting on `Category` instead of `Severity` and the sorting order should be `<` not `>`.

Comment: The "final step" you're looking for is to fold together all the `IssueStatus` instances with the same id. Something like this (copy and add formatting): `proc2.groupBy(_.resourceId).values.map(_.foldLeft(IssueStatus("", None, None, None)){
  case (IssueStatus(_,a,b,c),IssueStatus(id,x,y,z)) =>
    IssueStatus(id, a.fold(x)(Some(_)), b.fold(y)(Some(_)), c.fold(z)(Some(_))
    )
})` It's very inefficient but it appears to work.